# Azure group details retrieve from JWT token

Tags: angularjs, azure, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am working angular4 and my application is authenticated with AzureAD SSO.And also I am receiving JWT token from the application and send to my middle wire application and verifying this token from the middle for midle wire request security.
Now I need to access the group information from JWT toke? How to parse group information form JWT token ? Any suggestion please, thanks in advance.

Comment: where you want to retrive group info on client side(in javascript)? or somewhere else also can you post some expired sample token here

Comment: I need to retrieve group info from javascript or inside my middle wire (graphql), currently JWT token is available in both UI and middleware.Is there any option to parse group info from JWT token?

Comment: i think this one can help https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode i can create a fiddle if you can provide some sample token

Comment: Thank you @jitender but how to add group info into JWT token  from Azure

Comment: @Jamsheer Is the issue fixed? Please feel free to let me know if you still have problem about this issue.

Comment: @FeiXue Thank you for the reply.I got the group info now.Can I call graph API using JWT token (Generated through Azure adal-angualr implementation)?

Comment: Yes, you can call the graph API in the angular app. Did you got any specific issue?

Comment: Getting issue like {
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "",
            "date": "2017-10-11T08:36:06"
        }
    }
}

Comment: To call the Graph REST, we need to corresponding access token. Please check the `aud` in the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to see whether the value match the graph you were requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To issue group claims in the id_token, we need to change `groupMembershipClaims` to `SecurityGroup` or `All` in the manifest of the app.

> “SecurityGroup”    groups claim will contain the identifiers of all security groups of which the user is a member.
>
> “All”  groups claim will contain the identifiers of all security groups and all distribution lists of which the user is a member.

Here are some articles about group claims:

[Authorization in Cloud Applications using AD Groups](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/)

[Understanding the Azure Active Directory application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest)

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)